# I want to redirect from one form to another in dynamics 365 crm

Tags: javascript, c#

i have created a C# plugin to stop the lead to convert into opportunity after Qualify, but now i want to redirect from Lead to any other Entity (say Account or contact) whenever the lead is qualified. if someone have a good working answer/way please tell me.. thanku. code in C# or JavaScript will work better.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Create your plugin and register the step as shown on the image below.
Get the data from Target and the rest of logic it's up to you ...

[image]